# Bootstrap with font-weight: 500 looks "normal" on Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, typography

I'm using Bootstrap and setting an element to use `font-weight: 500` causes it to look medium/semi-bold in Chrome but normal-weight in Firefox on Windows:

Chrome:

[image: Element with medium-weight text in Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Same element in Firefox, with a normal weight]

How can I make it look semi-bold in both browsers?

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap's sans-serif font on Windows is "Segoe UI," which has support for the weights "normal" (400) and "semi-bold" (600) but not "medium" (500). In situations like this, Chrome rounds up to "semi-bold" while Firefox rounds down to "normal." Changing to 600 will achieve semi-bold in both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap `v5.2` has a `fw-semibold` class that can easily implement the "fix" (setting `font-weight: 600`). Especially useful in heading elements which are normally in bold anyway but Firefox would make them regular.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/text/#font-weight-and-italics